# Will solar fans go hand-in-hand with ridge vents and whole house fans?

Tags: attic, ventilation

I have ridge vents but I’m wanting to add a whole house fan and a solar attic fan.

Comment: The first part of this is a "product recommendation" ask, and as such off-topic. The rest is fine. Please [edit] to keep it on-topic by removing that part.

Comment: A solar fan would remove the most hot air when the need is greatest, so that would help with attic temps. The whole-house seems to be a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

They will definitely go hand in hand provided that the total free air venting will handle the CFM of the largest setting of the fan you select. Once you select the fan size, 3 x sq ft of house, you'll want 1 sq ft of free air for each 750 CFM of the largest speed of the fan. ex: 1320 sq ft house would need 3960 CFM fan. You choose a 3400/5400 two speed fan. You'll need 5400/750=7.2 sq ft of free air venting in your attic. Get the sq in of each vent, add them together and divide by 144 to get sq ft. Multiply that by 75% to allow for air flow restrictions in the vents.  So continuing on with the example, say you have 16 8"x15" vents so 1920 sq in of vents divided by 144 equals 13.33 sq ft times 75% equals 10 sq ft of free air venting so you're good to go.

If your venting in the attic isn't enough, you'll have to add more vents. Utilizing solar fans instead of free air venting would require coordinating the timing because the solar fans would need to be on when the whole house fan was on. If your solar fan didn't have a battery, you wouldn't be able to run the whole house fan at night, which would be a big disadvantage because that's when it's usually the coolest.

https://quietcoolsystems.com/whole-house-fan/how-to-size/

Comment: Just what I needed Jack! Thanks.